# rake jobs:work issue in implementing projectfedena

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, delayed-job

I am trying to implement fedena v 2.3. [projectfedena.org] which is an opensource school management app. I have a problem with a feature of
the fedena.

When I try to send internal messages, either the recipient doesn't receive
the message or it doesn't appear in the Sent Box.

The same problem is discussed in the fedena forum
http://www.projectfedena.org/forum/9-support-and-troubleshooting/topics/724-internal-messaging-service-is-not-working

I have to run "rake jobs:work" again and again to see the output

When i executed the rake command it worked  for me but the problem i dont know how to run it for everytime when it is needed.

The forum didn't give me a solution. I came across cron jobs, which runs
each and every minute which doesn't seem to be optimal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this

crontab -u root -e
then type the following and save

```
* * * * * cd <rails_source_dir> && RAILS_ENV=production <rake path> jobs:work
```

rake path = "which rake"

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using `delayed_job` in that project (I can't check it now, sadly github is down now) so you need to deamonize it instead of running it in foreground. How? [Here's](http://8raystech.com/2009/2/28/background-job-processing-in-rails-with-delayed_job) a great tutorial describing it, of course the easiest way of making delayed job run permanently would be to simply call on server:

```
rake jobs:work &
```

the `&` at the end will detach process from terminal and leave it running permanently, but that is not a very good way of resolving it, above link provides better approach.

Edit: GH is up now and i checked, indeed it is using delayed job so above link should help you.